# Do electrons follow wave like path or become waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

[image]

when an electron starts moving with high velocity does it move in a wave like path or become a wave itself?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what those pictures are and why you have included them?

Comment: This seems more philosophical than physical. If something follows a wave-like path, is it not a wave?

Comment: Even macroscopic classical waves (waves on a string, surface waves on liquids, sound waves, etc.) don't feature bits of matter that "follow [a] wave like path" if by that phrase you mean following a sinusoidal like path. Bits of matter in classical waves moves away from and then back to some resting position. For idealized waves on a string the motion is in a line perpendicular to the resting direction of the string. Water moves in ellisoids as a ripple passes. Air more to-and-fron *parallel* to the direction of sound propogation.

Comment: *Nothing* follows the wavy line in the graph. because the graph isn't a path, it's displacement as a function of position at a particular time *or* displacement as a function of time at a particular position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when an electron starts moving with high velocity does it move in a wave like path or become a wave itself?

In the present day  model for elementary particles, [the standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) the electron is a point particle with the given mass and other attributes shown in the table, which have been experimentally determined.

It is not a wave. What has a wave behavior is the  wavefunction $Ψ$ determining **the probability** of finding the electron at (x,y,z,t)  by the value of $Ψ^*Ψ$ , dependent on the boundary conditions of the specific problem.

The image you show is wrong. The electron, since there are no boundary conditions, will move in a straight line within the [Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html) constraints of its given  momentum.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to think of an electron as being like a surfer riding forward on the front of a wave.  The medium of the wave may be moving up and down but the surfer is moving forward in a straight line, along with the energy and momentum of the wave. (Note: The energy and momentum will continue moving forward with or without the surfer.)

Comment: So the energy and momentum of the electron can propagate even without an electron?

Comment: Perhaps without a point like "particle".  By the way, there is nothing associated with any kind of wave which follows a "wavelike" path.  Skiers and roller coasters may do that.  The medium for a wave oscillates in place.