# Twin slit experiment time between photons

Tags: quantum-mechanics

since it is possible to send a photon through the slits one at a time- what would be the maximum time gap between photons that would still allow an interference pattern to form?

Comment: Maybe me recent answer to a similar question here will help understand quantum mechanical interferences https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/511253/deny-of-wave-nature-of-matter/511290#511290

Comment: Is does not really matter how long between photons, the pattern will form whether it is days, years or picoseconds.

Comment: You could also take a jillion separate-but-identical double-slit experiments (separated in time, in space, or in both), send just one photon through each of them, and then overlay all jillion of the single-photon detection locations. You'll get the same interference pattern, even though each one of the jillion dots came from a separate experiment.

Answer (score 2):

In the double-slit interferometer, different photons do not interfere with each other.  Instead, each photon interferes with *itself*.

The double-slit interferometer is set up in such a way that it's not possible to know which slit the photon goes through - even after the photon is detected.

Suppose we shoot one single photon at a known time at the double slit, then detect the photon somewhere downstream.  We know where we detected the photon, and we know when we detected it; but we don't know which slit it went through.  We don't see an interference pattern; we just see the detection of one photon.

Now suppose we send a series of single photons through the double slit, and keep track of where each one is when it is detected.  We still won't know which slit each went through.  But when we map out the locations of all the detections together, we will see an interference pattern.  The standard (and almost certainly correct) interpretation is that *each* single photon is actually a wave that interferes with itself, producing an interference pattern whose squared amplitude at a point corresponds to the relative probability of detecting the photon at that point.  When we sum up all the detections of photons that have gone through the slits, we see an average of all the probability distributions.  If each photon is produced with the same frequency, all of the photon waves will be the same and will produce the same interference patterns.  Each detection is a separate sample of the same probability distribution, so by detecting a lot of identical photons we can map out the (square of) the photon wave function.

To repeat: the interference pattern in the double-slit interferometer experiment is due to each photon wave interfering with itself, not due to different photons interfering with each other.

Comment: *The standard (and almost certainly correct) interpretation is that each single photon is actually a wave that interferes with itself* Is this standard? Doesn't this equate the wavefunction to the particle itself?

Comment: The terminology is of course imprecise, since neither "particle" nor "wave" quite encompasses the right meaning.  If "photon" refers to the result of a detection event, that's quite different from using the term to refer to the physical entity that's traveling from the source to the detector, before the detection event.  A "photon detector" can't detect a wavefunction; it only *samples* the wavefunction analogously to the way the outcome of a roulette spin *samples* the probability weighting of a roulette wheel.

Comment: I agree with that. I just think saying it interferes with itself is a confusing way to explain it.

Comment: What's imprecise is the use of the word interference, it goes back over over 50 years as the observed pattern looked similar to that made by interfering water waves. Better to use a more modern Feynman "allowed paths" description where photons are known to only travel path lengths n times their wavelength.  For example when we set the mirrors wrong in a laser cavity we could say we have interference as no photons are produced or seen .... but we do get a viable photon wave function when the mirrors are set correctly and many photons are produced.

Comment: Are the photons really interfering with themselves when there is no lasing or is it better to say we just don't wave the correct path length (wave function) to produce them.

Comment: Your opinion is noted.  Not sure that the OP has the background to use the Feynman path integral.

Comment: @PhysicsDave, please clarify "Are the photons really interfering with themselves when there is no lasing or is it better to say we just don't wave the correct path length (wave function) to produce them."

Comment: In a laser when the mirrors are set wrong there is no photon production but the energy is available .... there is no viable path for the photons.  The we could call this interference  .... or we could just say the "we just don't wave the correct path length (wave function) to produce them."  The allowed photon paths are the main point here and are the reason that we have bright spots in the double slit pattern and lasing in the laser.  (And no photons in the dark spots and no photons in the misaligned laser.)

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes indeed no lasting is an interference of a photon with itself. Another interesting example is that a single photon can be emitted simultaneously by two synchronized lasers. In a double slit experiment, a single photon passes through both slits simultaneously. Similarly, with synchronized lasers, a single photon can be emitted by both simultaneously. A different way of saying the same is that the uncertainty principle doesn't allow us to know which of the lasers emitted the photon. And if you insist on knowing, the interference disappears just like in the double slit experiment.

Comment: Does your first sentence contain a typo?  Your second sentence is correct; as is your third.  The fourth sentence seems to be essentially a duplicate of the second.  The last sentence requires background: the interference disappears *if anything is done to try to measure which slit (or which laser) the photon comes from*.

Comment: @safesphere - In the case of the laser which is misaligned the voltage is applied but no current flows, i.e. no energy consumed, so I would NOT say the photons interfered, they were never created.  In your example of synced lasers, is it better to say a single photon was emitted but we do not know from which laser it was emitted .....?  ( I don't think 2 atoms, one in each laser, decided to emit half a photon!!??).

Comment: @PhysicsDave I am not sure what kind of lasers you are referring to. I used to work with neodymium glass and ruby lasers with optical excitement where all lamps energy is released as a light pulse regardless of the mirror alignment. On your second point, as I mentioned above, you can use the HUP indeed, but it doesn't give the full intuition. For example, you can see yourself in a mirror, because the wavefunction of each photon does not change phase (collapse) at the mirror, because each photon reflects off the entire mirror, not of a single electron, even if we don't know which one.

Comment: Any two lasers that can be phase-locked together, such as two HeHe lasers one of which has a movable cavity mirror driven by the phase difference between the two lasers.  The two beams interfere as if they come from a single laser.

Comment: @safesphere Laser diodes lase only when the mirrors are aligned, even external mirrors can change the power consumption. In your ruby laser example much of the pump light energy would be lost (i.e. not converted to laser photons) if the mirrors are not aligned, those lost photons would escape the cavity and be absorbed elsewhere.  It is interesting you mention that you say a photon reflects off the entire mirror, i.e more than 1 electron involved ... is this how 2 lasers emit one photon, i.e 2 or more electrons involved in the photon production?

Comment: @PhysicsDave In a ruby laser atoms get excited and emit the same amount of energy whether or not the mirrors are aligned, just not necessarily coherent or through the mirrors. In a stimulated emission the incoming and emitted photons are identical, so you cannot say which one is which. This is equivalent to each photon being emitted by all atoms simultaneously and each photon interfering with itself between the mirrors. Photons do not interact with each other, so no two photons can interfere ever, but only each with itself. The probability of finding one does not depend on the other.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Yes two or more synchronized lasers emitting a single photon together are similar to a single photon reflecting off the whole mirror or to passing trough both slits. As mentioned, there are two equivalent ways of looking at it. The "wave" way is that each photon interacts with all available electrons (or takes every available path). Here the photon is a wave and everything is very intuitive. The (less intuitive) "particle" way is via the HUP that the nature does not define, where the photon goes or what it interacts with (our knowledge is a result, not the cause of this behavior).

Comment: @PhysicsDave PS. The "particle" view is more common, because particles are observable while quantum waves are not directly observable (that plus professors enjoy confusing students on purpose). However personally IMHO the "wave" view is correct, even though we cannot see the waves directly, while the "particle" view is just a formal explanation to make ends meet artificially after the fact. At the end of the day the HUP itself is a consequence of the wave nature or matter, so the wave explanation must be more fundamental.